# Dimension of the eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can an eigenvector have rank>1 ?

I have encountered such evecs but couldnt know how to express them in *S*. Or I might have done some calculation mistakes.

Comment: What is the rank of a vector ??

Comment: Eigenvectors do not have ranks, linear transformations have ranks, eigenvectors are just single elements in a vector space.

Comment: Your question makes little sense as written. What is $S$? In any case, the rank of an $m\times n$ matrix is at most the minimum of $m$ and $n$. So the rank of a vector, construed as a linear mapping, is at most 1. Perhaps you mean to ask about the *dimension* of the *eigenspace*, not the rank of an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single vector, regarded as a matrix, has rank $0$ (if it is the $0$ vector) or $1$.  Perhaps what you mean is that an eigenspace (the space of vectors $x$ satisfying $A x = \lambda x$ for some particular $\lambda$) has dimension $> 1$?

Comment: No thanks for the answer